Why are my .NET application variables disappearing on my web server?
Background
Application/Program: lightweight website (40,000 HTML pages | 5 .ASPX pages).
Goal: use application variables (.NET) ~ via Global.asax
Problem: web server is failing to use application variables (yet dev environment is fine)
Desire: web server uses application variables
Tech Specs

Development environment: IIS 10.0 (IIS Express)
Production environment: IIS 8.0 (web server)
Server-side: .ASPX webforms; Visual Basic
Connection/communication: one server/domain (ie, no web farms; no web gardens)

Details

In my development environment, my application variables are working fine (ie, 100% success rate)

On my web server, though, my application variables are failing (0% success rate)


Code - Global.asax.vb:
Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Application("fooBar") = "Hello, World"
End Sub

MyPage.aspx:
<script runat="server">
  Protected Function EmbedMe() As String
    Return Application("fooBar")
  End Function
</script>


<nav><%: EmbedMe() %></nav>

Troubleshooting
So far, I've tried to solve my problem in the following ways:

Adding/removing my Global.asax file [on the web server]
Adding/removing certain project files[on the web server] (eg,obj*; packages*`; etc.)
Restarting the IIS Web Site on my web server
Examining the application pool on my web server (I haven't made any changes, though)
Using a different IIS Web Site on my web server
Researching this problem (on StackOverflow.com; on Google.com; on Bing.com; etc.)

Request
May you please help me get my web server to respect/use my .NET application variables?
Thanks

Is there anything in the Windows event logs on the server to suggest something is going wrong? Can you use IIS for development so that you're working with the actual software environment the site will use instead of IIS Express? Windows Server 2012 is somewhat out of date, is there any chance of moving to something more recent that is not beyond the end of support?

I ran your code on IIS 11 and it works. On IIS 8 try to use equal sign = instead of colon :.  <% =EmbedMe() %>.

@AlexKudryashev Okay. I've just tried that. Unfortunately, though, it didn't solve my problem. My server still isn't respecting my .NET application variable

@AndrewMorton Answer #1 = No, there isn't anything in my Windows event logs. I looked in inetPub\Logs\ , and everything in there looked fine (ie, I found an HTTP Response of 200). I also checked my inetPub\FailedReqLogFiles\, and everthing in there looked fine (ie, no xml files for my HTTP requests). Answer #2 = I suppose I could use a different IIS version [on my dev-environment and/or server]. It's just that I'd prefer to avoid software updates/upgrades. Please Help Thanks.

Well, keep in mind that the application object is global to all users. And keep in mind that any un-handled errors can and will trigger a app pool restart, and thus that means the values are lost. Also, if you using a web farm, or cloud hosting, then multiple instances of the web site can exist, and memory based (such as Application("some value") thus will not persist between page post-backs. However, it does not look like you are running a web farm, but if you are, then Application() of course can't be used, nor can it be if you using a load balancing setup (this does not seem to be your case

However, the app pool pipeline DOES need to be setup as "integrated" for this to work. So, check the app pool settings on IIS. As noted, using Applicaiton() not all that reliable if app pool restarts are occuring, and as noted, app pool re-starts can often occur if code errors out.

@Elias Your development and production environments are different, so you should expect it to not work when transferring from one to the other. Where you'll find a Windows 8 machine to develop on I don't know, and you might not be able to find an old-enough version of Visual Studio to run on it.

@AlbertD.Kallal Okay, I've checked my AppPool. Its pipeline value was already set to integrated . So, my server was already failing with that value. Longstoryshort, that hasn't solved it (ie, I'm still stuck). Please Help

So, you never see a value in Application(), or that a whole lot of the time the value is gone missing? If always, then we need to dig further. If "often", then as noted, any application error will trigger a app pool restart, and then all values are lost(). If you create a new quick test page, and with two buttons, btn1 can set a value. And then have btn2 shove the value into a text box on that page. So, try creating a quick test page, and see if that works. We want to narrow down between never works, or "often" does not work. If this works on the given page, then we can dig deeper.

so, what I am saying, is build a test page, and btn1 sets the Applicaton("test") some value, and then btn2 can take that value and say shove it into a text box. This quick test will show/prove that Application() can work. This  THEN suggests the issue is application start code stub in Global is NOT running, and this is a common issue. So, perhaps the issue is that your global start routine is not running.....Also, remove (check for) a PrecompiledApp.config file - this file should be removed.

@AlbertD.Kallal You're onto something. On my Web Server, the Global.asax routine was never running. So – after doing some minor code displacement – I was able to get my Web Server to successfully use/display my application variable. Altogether, I'm closer to a solution (ie, √ .NET Variables; X Global.asax not running). Please Help

@Elias Does the Global.asax.vb file start with Public Class Global_asax : Inherits HttpApplication ? (It could be on two lines insted of having a colon.)

@AndrewMorton Yes, it does. In VB, it reads like this: Public Class Global_asax [newLine] Inherits HttpApplication

REAL SOLUTION
Place the following three files onto the webserver:

~/bin/App_global.asax.compiled
~/bin/App_global.asax.dll
~/PrecompiledApp.config


REAL ISSUE
The real problem was that my Web Server was not executing Application_Start(). The reason it wasn't firing was, apparently, because my Web Server was not running my Global.asax file.

REAL PROBLEM
My web server was missing three files:

~/bin/App_global.asax.compiled
~/bin/App_global.asax.dll
~/PrecompiledApp.config

Reason: I presume that it was missing those files because I don't use VS2019's Publish functionality. Instead, I just: (i) compile my website application; and (ii) copy my files onto my webserver (via a [selective] batch file).

REAL WARNING/DISCLAIMER
You will probably need to recycle the ApplicationPool on your WebServer!! For me – despite adding those files – my web server [still] wouldn't fire the Application_Start() routine (and, thus, create my Application Variables) until I recycled my ApplicationPool

¹ small note: apparently, it doesn't matter if those three [aforementioned] files are very outdated. My files had timestamps from 4 years ago, yet all of my updates were working.
² smaller note: apparently, the web server doesn't need these three files in order to execute your .aspx and/or .html files properly.

SUMMARY
Just copy those three files onto your webserver and you should start seeing your  Application Variables on your website/webapp (all [other] things being equal, of course).
I hope this can help you.
Best Wishes.

Better to simply create a global class with the values you want, and then create a public function that checks if the class is already in session, and if not, the function can shove the class into session. Then, next time you call that function (that returns the class with values), then it can use/check session, or if out of session, it puts the class back into session. Hence, the class becomes "self healing". All in all your troubles are ALL due to a poor deployment approach. And really, using application start is a global function - not for each user, and not a great approach anyway.
